# Linq to Entities, EntityReferences and DataGridViews

Tags: linq, datagridview, entityreference

I am trying to select certain fields from my entity to be used as the datasource for a datagridview, but I haven't been able to make it work.  Is such a thing possible?  For example, I have a Customers entity that contains several entityreferences.  I want to take fields from the customers entity and from within those entityreferences and display them in the datagridview.  I haven't been able to come up with a Linq query to accomplish this, and even when you simply use the entire entity as the datasource the fields within the entityreferences are not displayed.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from customer in context.customers
select new 
{
    Name = customer.Name,
    City = customer.Address.City
}
```

that will create a custom object and you can see the second property is referencing an entity field on the primary entity.. basically just transform the data to a new object and bind the enumerable generated to the grid.

sorry if this is a little mumbled, typing on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: This is not tested with entity framework references.

When using object data sources you can reference properties of object references, but you must first cast the object:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text='<%# ((Customer)Container.DataItem).Address.City%>'></asp:Label>
```

Could this be your problem accessing properties of the entity references?